# Dimension of hilbert spaces for identical particles

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, fermions, bosons

Now consider two particles occupying $N$ distinct states |1>, |2>, · · · , |$N$>. What is the Hilbert-space dimension of this two-particle system if the two particles are :

> (a) Distinguishable?
>
> (b) Identical Bosons?
>
> (c) Identical fermions (assuming their spins are polarized, so the spin-part is completely symmetric)?

**My thoughts are**:

> a) It should just be $N^2$
>
> b) Just $N$ since they're identical
>
> c) Due to Pauli exclusion would it be $N^2$ - $N$ since they have to be different states?

Can anyone check me?

Comment: Think of the states as $N\times 1$ column matrices. The two particle state is an $N\times N$ matrix. For bosons, you need a symmetrical matrix. That has $N(N+1)/2$ distinct terms. For fermions you need an antisymmetrical matrix. That has $N(N-1)/2$ distinct terms.